# is it some bug in firefox or jquery or i doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I want to change hidden input value on div click, so i do following:

```
$('#gallery').click(function(){
        if ($('input[name=isgallery]').attr('value') == '0') {
            $('input[name=isgallery]').attr('value', '1')
        }
        else {
            $('input[name=isgallery]').attr('value', '0')
        }
        $('#filterform').attr('action',$('#filterform').attr('act'));
        alert('ok');
        $('#filterform').submit();
    }
    );
```

when it equals 0 i change it to 1 and otherwise
but it did not work
and following code works:

```
$('#gallery').click(function(){
        if ($('input[name=isgallery]').attr('value') == '0') {
            $('input[name=isgallery]').attr('value', '0')
        }
        else {
            $('input[name=isgallery]').attr('value', '1')
        }
        $('#filterform').attr('action',$('#filterform').attr('act'));
        alert('ok');
        $('#filterform').submit();
    }
    );
```

and also, when i delete the function at all it still works
and form submits

maybe i have one more handler for this div, but i can't find one

you can check it on 
http://www.4block.org/en/museum/posters
and click "gallery view" on top-right

Answer (score 2):

This should work a little better cross-browser, plus less DOM traversing to find elements :)

```
$('#gallery').click(function(){
  $('input[name=isgallery]').each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val() == '0' ? '1' : '0');
  });
  $('#filterform').attr('action',$('#filterform').attr('act')).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to change an input's value.